# Does any country allow a foreign national without blood ties to the country to be a diplomat?

Tags: citizenship, international-relations

Currently, is there some country which has diplomats born abroad and without any ancestry in its people?

I heard it is possible in United States, but is there any other country in world where it is possible?

[Mrs. Albright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_Albright) is not an example for this question because she migrated to USA with her family when she was 11 y/o, in 1948. I'm talking about how could an adult person be a diplomat in different country.

In other words, could an American citizen or a Brazilian citizen, for example, represent any other country as its diplomat? Which countries? Would they be accepted as candidates?

**EDIT - More information**

In Brazil, for example, the candidate must be native Brazilian ("[Ser brasileiro nato](http://www.institutoriobranco.mre.gov.br/pt-br/concurso_de_admissao_a_carreira_diplomatica.xml)"), that is - according Brazilian constitution - a) simply born in Brazil (“[jus soli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli)”); b) born abroad, with at least one Brazilian parent (“[jus sanguinis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_sanguinis)”). So, according this criteria, even the most talented diplomat in the world could not be a member of Brazilian Ministry of Foreign Affairs as a diplomat. Excepting his/her country, could he/she find another country?

Comment: Oh, down voters... if you think this question is not appropriated for this community, OK, but please help me to find a better place to post it :)

Comment: You do not need to be born in the United States to be a member of the United States government.  You can google this easily. /close

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad. Do you expect the crowd here to search the regulations of every nation to see if there is one that doesn't allow foreigners to be diplomats?

Comment: Can you show at least an example of the list of diplomats of a country and show that diplomats with foreign-sounding names have some ancestry in the given country ?

Comment: So many times when I was Googling something, I would come across a forum post with someone who had the exact same question. And sometimes the answer would be "You can google this easily". And my reaction would be, if you don't want to provide an answer, then why are you saying anything at all? Now I have to hit the back button and find another page that hopefully answered my question. Fortunately Stackoverflow changed all that. But unfortunately, you can't seem to get rid of these negative zealots. Btw, I upvoted this because I thought it was a valid question.

Comment: @dan-klasson No one is claiming this is an easy google search; quite the opposite. A question requiring an exhaustive search of every nation is too broad.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Who said this question had anything to do with a specific country? What if someone would like to know whether this actually happened, at some point in history? Yeah they couldn't, because the zealots striked again.

Comment: @dan-klasson you really got the point!

Comment: Article 8 of the Vienna Convention clearly contemplates that this can happen, but that the receiving state must agree to it: Article 8 1. Members of the diplomatic staff of the mission should in principle be of the nationality of the sending State. 2. Members of the diplomatic staff of the mission may not be appointed from among persons having the nationality of the receiving State, except with the consent of that State which may be withdrawn at any time. 3. The receiving State may reserve the same right with regard to nationals of a third State who are not also nationals of the sending State.

Comment: What are you hoping to learn by asking this question?  I think most with country's it is possible, but unlikely because in most cases the country is going to want to make sure that it has their interests at heart.

Comment: Maybe someone want to be a diplomat, but their country's aplication process is too hard and then they could offer their talent to another country. In this case, it is someone who has foreign affairs at heart, above all.

Comment: @VictorFS May I suggest a career as [Apostolic Nuncio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_diplomacy)? Being born in the Vatican is definitely not a requirement.

Comment: @Relaxed I was not expecting this answer, but yeah, The Holy See is a option, u r right ^^ Don't you know something... faster?

Comment: Not a diplomat but I can provide an example of a high-ranking civil servant with a similar level of responsibilities in the ministry of defense of France: [Marwan Lahoud](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marwan_Lahoud).

Answer (score 5):

Former Secretary of State [Madeleine Albright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madeleine_Albright) was both born outside USA and had no ancestry here.

For a more curious historical example, [James Spens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Spens_%28diplomat%29) was both an ambassador from England to Sweden, AND at the same time (despite not having any Swedish roots - or for that matter as far as I know, English roots, being a Scottish noble) effectively Swedish King's Gustav Adolph's ambassador to England.

Comment: Nice answer. Mrs Albright went to USA when she was 11 y/o, in 1948.

Comment: There's also Henry Kissenger.  But both he and Albright were naturalized, so not "foreigners" as specified in the title.  The body says "foreign-born," of course, which is confusingly different.

Comment: Yes, I see USA is more flexible than Brazil. In Brazil you have to be a "native Brazilian"

Comment: Oops, i misspelled *Kissinger.*

Answer (score 4):

Your edit suggests a slightly different question but I don't think restrictions like Brazil's are common. I do not have any specific example at hand but a foreign-born ambassador seems possible in just about any European country I know.

Whether it's becoming part of the civil service, enlisting in the military, getting security clearance, etc. nearly all the restrictions I have ever encountered are about citizenship. Once you are citizen, you are in principle eligible for everything, ancestry or place of birth are not relevant legally speaking. Incidentally, unlike Brazil, simply being born in the country does not make you a citizen anywhere in Europe.

Which is not to say that there are many naturalized citizens in the highest echelons of the diplomatic service, recruitment can be much more narrow than this in practice.

Comment: Exactly: Brazil adopted jus soli and most of Europe adopted jus sanguinis.

Comment: @VictorFS Almost all American countries have unrestricted *ius soli*, it could be interested to see if there are restrictions there.

Comment: @VictorFS As you are probably aware, most American countries also have *jus sanguinis* for citizens' children who are not born in the country's territory.  The example of Ted Cruz has been in the news now and again; he was born in Canada of a US-citizen mother, so until he renounced his Canadian citizenship he was a citizen of both countries.

Comment: Many european countries also additionally allow citizenship for people born here. Sometimes with limitations, like if you are born in Germany without German parents, you'll get the citizenship as long as you are minor (along with your parent's one), but then you'll have to decide which one to keep.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I didn't know this rule, that's interesting. As far as I know, being granted citizenship at birth based purely on the place of birth is quite rare in Europe, outside of very specific cases (e.g. people who would otherwise be stateless). Do you know any other country than Germany with a similar rule?

Comment: Actually, it's a bit less simple than I've told: one parent must have been in Germany for at least 8 years (and be a permanent resident at the time of the birth). And [in 2014 this "needs to choose" was limited](https://www.bmi.bund.de/EN/topics/migration/obligation-one-citizenship/obligation-one-citizenship-node.html) to those not growing up in Germany (and not being a dual citizen of another EU country or Switzerland).

Comment: Wikipedia's [Jus soli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_soli#Europe) article has some other examples of "restricted jus soli" for some European countries.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I am very familiar with France and all of these examples are similar and typical of what I had in mind: Citizenship by birth for people who would otherwise be stateless and a simplified path to citizenship later in life if you grow up in the country (with various nuances depending on the country). Portugal comes the closest but you still need to apply for citizenship, simply being born there and fulfilling all the conditions (which are pretty light) is not enough to become a citizen by birth.